# Rails - own hash inside params[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have many products in my application. User can choose some of them. Then I generate partial with chosen products. And I assign a name to each chosen product, because I want to have an access to them in my controller via params[].

My question is: How can I create something like a hash with all chosen products? Then I could get the products like params[:chosen-products] instead params[:quantity-id]. Is it possible?
I'm not sure if I can use any form_for because my view is quiet complicated (there is one form_for etc.)

```
<% @chosen_products.each do |product| %>
   <input name="quantity-<%=product.id %>" id="quantity-<%=product.id %>" class="product-quantity" type="number" step="0.01" >
<% end %>
```

@chosen_prodcuts.inspect for 2 products:

```
[#<Product id: 6, name: "Jogurt", kalorycznosc: 100.0, woda: 2.0, bialko: 2.0, bialkoZwierzece: 2.0, bialkoRoslinne: 2.0, tluszcz: 2.0, weglowodany: 2.0, blonnik: 2.0, laktoza: 2.0, sacharoza: 2.0, cholesterol: 2.0, sod: 2.0, potas: 2.0, wapn: 2.0, fosfor: 2.0, magnez: 2.0, zelazo: 2.0, cynk: 2.0, miedz: 2.0, mangan: 2.0, retinol: 2.0, betaKaroten: 2.0, witD: 2.0, witE: 2.0, witB1: 2.0, witB2: 2.0, witB3: 2.0, witB6: 2.0, foliany: 2.0, witB12: 2.0, witC: 2.0, fenyloalanina: 2.0, ogolemNasyconeKwTl: 2.0, ogolemJednoKwTl: 2.0, ogoleWieloKwTl: 2.0, stosunekWieloKwTl: 2.0, measure: nil, conversion: nil, alias: nil, user_id: 1, group_id: 2, created_at: "2015-11-26 23:01:57", updated_at: "2015-11-27 22:28:02">, #<Product id: 7, name: "Ser biały2", kalorycznosc: 200.0, woda: nil, bialko: nil, bialkoZwierzece: nil, bialkoRoslinne: nil, tluszcz: nil, weglowodany: nil, blonnik: nil, laktoza: nil, sacharoza: nil, cholesterol: nil, sod: nil, potas: nil, wapn: nil, fosfor: nil, magnez: nil, zelazo: nil, cynk: nil, miedz: nil, mangan: nil, retinol: nil, betaKaroten: nil, witD: nil, witE: nil, witB1: nil, witB2: nil, witB3: nil, witB6: nil, foliany: nil, witB12: nil, witC: nil, fenyloalanina: nil, ogolemNasyconeKwTl: nil, ogolemJednoKwTl: nil, ogoleWieloKwTl: nil, stosunekWieloKwTl: nil, measure: "porcja", conversion: 70.0, alias: "twarożek", user_id: 1, group_id: 2, created_at: "2015-11-26 23:01:58", updated_at: "2015-11-27 21:54:06">]
```

Product.rb (quiet long):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :group
 has_many :ingredients
 has_many :meals, :through => :ingredients

 validates :user_id, presence: true
 validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
 validates :alias, length: {maximum: 50}
 validates :measure, length: {maximum: 50}
 validates :conversion, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true

 validates :kalorycznosc, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :woda, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :bialko, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :bialkoRoslinne, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :bialkoZwierzece, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :tluszcz, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :weglowodany, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :blonnik, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :laktoza, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :sacharoza, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :cholesterol, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :sod, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :potas, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :wapn, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :fosfor, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :magnez, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :zelazo, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :cynk, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :miedz, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :mangan, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :retinol, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :betaKaroten, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witB1, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witB2, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witB3, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witB6, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witB12, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witC, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witD, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :witE, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :foliany, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :fenyloalanina, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :ogolemJednoKwTl, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :ogolemNasyconeKwTl, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :ogoleWieloKwTl, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
 validates :stosunekWieloKwTl, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Comment: can you paste how `@chosen_products` looks with inspect? also paste the product model.

Comment: I would recommend you to use [Rails' form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-number_field_tag) since the `input` in your first code example looks a little bit messy. So for example: `<%= number_field_tag :"quantity-#{product.id}", class: 'product-quantity', step: '0.01' %>`. This generates the same HTML markup but is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<% chosen_products_csv = @chosen_products.map{|p| p.id }.join(',') %>
<input name="chosen_products" id="chosen_products class="product-quantity" type="text" step="0.01" value="<%= chosen_products_csv %>" >
```

It will give you an input whose value is coma separated list of product ids.

Then in you controller you could to this to retrieve the products:

```
unless params['chosen_products'].blank?
  product_ids = params['chosen_products'].split(',').map{|p| p.to_i }
  @products = Product.where(id: product_ids) if product_ids.length > 1 || product_ids.first != 0
end
```

You did not specify how these chosen products get assigned to the form, but for the example above, you could have it as hidden field, and add the value by javascript before the form submition.

Comment: In fact, I have this value(chosen_products) in my controller, but in different action (triggered by ajax). Is an option to get this value also in create action?

Comment: in case  `params['chosen_products']` is nil? I would definitely say this is a very dangerous answer! You could write it more better.  why not making a different call and safe checking inside?

Comment: of course, you are right, this was meant as an idea how it may be achieved, because the OP did not provide any controller code into which the solution may be fit. I have changed it per your suggestion anyway.